# Why does "Resume" fix an Access 3197 error

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am running into a really perplexing situation with a bound Access splitform. My form is bound to query which is linked to a SQL database.

I have a method which is called by some form controls on their "on click" event as follows:

```
Private Function UpdateCheckBoxCaption(ByRef p_label As Label, p_fieldName As String, Optional p_newStatus As String = "") As Boolean

    UpdateCheckBoxCaption = False

    Dim errCount As Integer
    errCount = 0

    'check if value already exists, it can't be overwritten then
    If DoesFieldContainData(Me.Recordset, p_fieldName) = False Then
        Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure you want to set this date?" _
                        & vbCrLf & "" _
                        & vbCrLf & "Only the manager can undo this change." _
                        , vbYesNo Or vbExclamation Or vbDefaultButton1, "Please confirm")

        Case vbYes
            On Error GoTo errHandler
            With Me.Recordset
                .Edit
                .Fields(p_fieldName) = Now
                .Update
            End With

            UpdateCheckBoxCaption = True

        Case vbNo

        End Select

    Else
        MsgBox "This date was already set to " & Me.Recordset.Fields(p_fieldName)
    End If

    Exit Function

errHandler:
    errCount = errCount + 1
    If Err.Number = 3197 Then
        Debug.Print "error number "; CStr(errCount)
        If errCount < 10 Then
            Resume
        End If
    End If

    MsgBox "Error in UpdateCheckBoxCaption"

End Function
```

It is perplexing because I can simply add the basic "error handling" (using this term loosely as it's not really proper error handling) and cause the problem to go away by invoking `Resume.` I can also put a breakpoint on the `.Edit` line and step over the code with no error.

After more digging, it seems the DoesFieldContainData function is actually causing the problem here. If I remove that call the method works fine.

Which leads me to believe that the method here does not "release" the Recordset. And something about doing `Resume` causes it to happen.

Here is my DoesFieldContainData method (which is in a different module):

```
Public Function DoesFieldContainData(ByRef p_rs As DAO.Recordset, p_fieldName As String) As Boolean

    'returns "true" if field is valid data
    'returns "false" if field is either null or ""

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    DoesFieldContainData = True

    If IsNull(p_rs.Fields(p_fieldName)) = True Then
        DoesFieldContainData = False
    End If

    If p_rs.Fields(p_fieldName) = "" Then
        DoesFieldContainData = False
    End If

    Exit Function
errHandler:
    DoesFieldContainData = False

End Function
```

The onClick events look like:

```
Private Sub lbl_chk_concept2Review_Click()
    UpdateCheckBoxCaption Me.Controls("lbl_chk_concept2Review"), "DateConceptReviewHeld2"
End Sub
```

What I don't understand is why this is even causing a 3197 record lock problem - what am I missing?

---

The sequence of events is:

1. Move record to a new record in a SplitForm view
2. Click a label to cause the following methods to execute

   - "On_Click"
   - This calls `UpdateCheckBoxCaption` immediately with
   - This is ONLY code execution
   - This executes with no "error" debug printing
3. Repeat above step on a different label

   - On all subsequent steps, the debug statement fires at least one time (sometimes twice)

As best I can tell, having set breakpoints on all methods, no other code fires other than an `On_Current` method that happens the first time I move records and the above twice in a row.

Comment: Does the error happen 'every time', or random? How many users are active at the time when it occurs? You first need to determine if it is truly a multi-user issue, or something else. Since I don't know the big picture of how or what your application is doing, it could be a simple fix to 'lock' the record for a very brief update, then close it. But that would require code to handle the OTHER user that wants/needs to lock (i.e. a pause of .5 seconds or so).

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn at this point it is me as the single user.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Sorry, missed the first question. It is always happening.

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) Have you tried my suggestion to review "Locals" window (see below); (2) Can you trace the ENTIRE series of events? You mentioned triggered by 'on click' event, but Without seeing all your code, is it possible some other subroutine / function / etc. is 'touching' the data? Can you share the chain of events and that code?

Comment: The above is called immediately on a button click. The only code called is the functions above (other than the "on_Click") event. I HAVE noticed this error only appears on the *second* time this is called when I transition records. I will update the question

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I updated my question. The only recordset being opened is the SplitForm recordset and I added the entire chain of events.

Comment: Let's be clear... One place you say "Click a label to cause..", another you say "..on a button click...". Please answer ALL of the following: (1) Is it Label or Button, and please show the code you have in that event click; (2) Do you have these types of events for MULTIPLE fields/labels? (3) Are you clicking on a LABEL, or Text Box?  I have created your environment (Access/SQL Server) and when I click twice, I just get the "This date was already set to" message?!?!

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47883/discussion-between-enderland-and-wayne-g-dunn)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be in a loop, so it seems like you're only passing through the function once.  The "Resume" doesn't **fix** the problem, it merely moves to the next line and continues on its way.

The issue might be happening because you're not closing p_rs.  Make sure you close that recordset before you exit.

Comment: Resume causes code execution to happen on the line of code where the error was thrown. This is easy to cause infinite loops with, generally, because of this, which is why I have a counter there. Closing p_rs causes my form recordset to close as well since it's ByRef (though with ByVal the same thing happens).

Comment: Note that "Resume Next" causes the line to be skipped, which is what you are likely thinking of.

Comment: Just a thought... what OTHER forms/recordsets/tables are possibly open at the moment this happens. If not sure, place your breakpoint where the error will occur, then go to view "Locals" window and see what may be in use.